Extract gbif occurrences within a geographic administrative area with rgbif
I would like to extract all occurrences for a Canadian province for a given taxa with rgbif. I am following this tutorial : https://docs.ropensci.org/rgbif/articles/getting_occurrence_data.html
It mentions that we can use the gadm instead of the polygonal boundaries but I can't figure out the code. My real area that I am want should be CAN11_1. I am trying to simplify the code from here and adapt to my taxa. This simplified code works:
occ_download(
  pred("taxonKey", 2436775),
 pred("gadm","ETH"),
  format = "SIMPLE_CSV")

However, this code using phylumKey instead of taxonKey does not work. The error message says that the problem is the pred("gadm", "ETH").
occ_download(
  pred("phylumKey", 35),
 pred("gadm","ETH"),

  format = "SIMPLE_CSV")

This code works but is not the correct polygon.
occ_download(
  pred_in("phylumKey", c(35, 9, 13)), # important to use pred_in
  pred_within("POLYGON((-70 47,-69 47,-69 49,-70 49,-70 47))"),
  format = "SIMPLE_CSV"
)

What am I missing???

You can use pred_and() with two separate pred() calls. Two separate unwrapped pred() calls e.g. not using pred_in() should work too.
When that error was returned, it seems like for some reason pred_in() was expecting a list object, although it does work with a single value.
library(rgbif)

# Request data (omit user, pwd, and email if already added to .Renviron)
occ_download(pred_and(pred("phylumKey", 35), pred("gadm","ETH")),
             format = "SIMPLE_CSV",
             user = "your_gbif_username",
             pwd = "your_gbif_password",
             email = "your_gbif_email")

# Check download status using occurrence number,
# see result in console from previous step
occ_download_wait("download occurrence number")

# Load data
df <- occ_download_get("download occurrence number") %>%
  occ_download_import()

head(df)
# # A tibble: 6 × 50
#     gbifID datasetKey    occurrenceID kingdom phylum class order family genus species
#    <int64> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
# 1 92657932 85042096-f76… ""           Plantae Bryop… Spha… Spha… Sphag… Spha… Sphagn…
# 2 92643197 85042096-f76… ""           Plantae Bryop… Bryo… Brya… Mniac… Pohl… Pohlia…
# 3 92630747 85042096-f76… ""           Plantae Bryop… Bryo… Dicr… Dicra… Para… Parale…
# 4 92629842 85042096-f76… ""           Plantae Bryop… Bryo… Bart… Bartr… Phil… Philon…
# 5 92622427 85042096-f76… ""           Plantae Bryop… Bryo… Brya… Mniac… Mnium Mnium …
# 6 92622418 85042096-f76… ""           Plantae Bryop… Bryo… Brya… Mniac… Plag… Plagio…
# # ℹ 40 more variables: infraspecificEpithet <chr>, taxonRank <chr>,
# #   scientificName <chr>, verbatimScientificName <chr>,
# #   verbatimScientificNameAuthorship <chr>, countryCode <chr>, locality <chr>,
# #   stateProvince <chr>, occurrenceStatus <chr>, individualCount <int>,
# #   publishingOrgKey <chr>, decimalLatitude <dbl>, decimalLongitude <dbl>,
# #   coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <dbl>, coordinatePrecision <dbl>, elevation <dbl>,
# #   elevationAccuracy <dbl>, depth <lgl>, depthAccuracy <lgl>, eventDate <chr>, …


Thanks so much! I managed to get it to work. I did need pred_in because my full query is for three phylla but it only works within the pred_and structure that you showed me. pred_and(pred_in("phylumKey", c(35, 9, 13)), pred("gadm", "ETH")) . I don't understand why the phylumKey requires the wrapping with pred_and while taxonKey does not but at least it works!

As mentioned in my answer, Two separate pred() calls ... will work too. Weird thing is, I ran your original code this morning and it worked. Updated the text to be clearer.

That's odd because two separate pred() calls did not work for me (with unhelpful error message). Oh, well, as long as it works with pred_and() as a wrapper.

@L Tyrone I ran my original code and it worked today! A big mystery. I don't remember updating my package since August.
